# Question about if and only if condition of point to be a limit point of a given set M in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Theorem: In a metric space, a necessary and sufficient condition for a point x to be a limit point of set M is that there exists a sequence {$_$} of distinct points of M converging to it.

Question: How should one show the only if direction? If I pick an arbitrary point p that is belongs to the set (contact points)\ (limit points). Let d denote the minimal distance from p to any limit point of M and find a sequence of open ball centered at p with radius $\frac{d}{n+1}$, that is {$_\frac{d}{n+1}(p)$} . And then pick a sequence of distinct point at each ball, hence under this construction I will build a sequence of distinct points of M converging to p but clearly by assumption p is not a limit point of set M.

The theorem is from INTRODUCTORY REAL ANALYSIS by Kolmogorov at page 48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of distinct elements of $M$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$, then, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies d(x_n,x)<\varepsilon$. This shows that every open ball centered at $x$ contains points of $M$. Besides, since the points of the sequence are distinct, then at most one of them is equal to $x$. So, this proves that every open ball centered at $x$ contains points of $M$ distinct from $x$. Therefore, $x$ is a limit point of $M$.

Comment: The definition for limit point is following, I copied which from wikipedia.                    
A point x in X is a limit point  of S if every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point of S different from x itself.                                  But what you show only tells us x is a contact point of M.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up finding I made some mistakes in understanding the definition of limit points and also finding your answer helpful.